# How to retrieve last inserted row in a teradata table using SQL

Tags: sql, teradata

I have the below multiset teradata table

```
CREATE MULTISET TABLE pp_scratch.HADOOP_FPTI_DASHBOARD ,NO FALLBACK ,
     NO BEFORE JOURNAL,
     NO AFTER JOURNAL,
     CHECKSUM = DEFAULT,
     DEFAULT MERGEBLOCKRATIO
     (
      job_status VARCHAR(32) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC NOT NULL,
      current_processing_hr VARCHAR(32) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC NOT NULL,
      no_of_files_moved VARCHAR(10) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC NOT NULL)
PRIMARY INDEX upi_HADOOP_FPTI_DASHBOARD ( current_processing_hr );
```

When I am trying to insert the values it is not in the order I have inserted. If it is in order I have inserted then I will retrieve the value by using order by statement. In this case how to retrieve the last inserted value.

Sample data

[image]

Comment: If Teradata is like every other RDBMS, there is no concept of 'insert order'.  What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: is there any possibility to retrive last inserted row in a table?

Comment: @GopiGowtham . . . If you specify the insert order, then you can get the last inserted row.  This would typically be with an `identity` column or a creation date timestamp.

Comment: There is no such thing as the "last row of a table" in a relational database. A table is like a basket full of balls it is not "sorted" so there can't be a "last row"

Comment: The identity column in Teradata does not guarantee order. A generated sequence number or a timestamp with ample precision are better alternatives. Identity columns in Teradata come with a bunch of baggage.

Answer (score 2):

Teradata tables are hash partitoned/sorted, there's no way to get the *last row* unless `current_processing_hr` is unique.

And you data types are wrong:

- change`current_processing_hr` to a `timestamp(2) default current_timestamp(2)`, if you don't insert multiple rows in the same 1/100th second you can use this for the *last row*
- change `no_of_files_moved` to `INT`

Answer (score 0):

What you can do here is add a sequence ( auto increment numeric integer ). For this you would have to alter your table and add a new column ( datatype integer ). 
This column will automatically increment its counter by 1 with every record you insert. Now, if you order by that new column, you will be able to get the last row which was inserted into the table.

Comment: No, not in a parallel system like Teradata, an `identity` is not sequential, in fact it's multiple sequences with different ranges of values, one per PE/AMP